# Which chart type counts the amount of timestamp instances inside a column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-charts

Last week, I wanted to count the amount of times an exception occured in a logfile.
Therefore, I had done a `grep "Exception"` in my file and used an `awk -F "." '{print $1}'` to show only the timestamps, the result looked as follows ("Tijdstip" is Dutch for "timestamp"):

```
Tijdstip
07:18:24
07:18:24
07:25:10
07:25:10
07:25:31
07:34:18
07:34:18
07:34:18
...
```

Then, I wanted to show the amount of times that timestamp was shown, which I did using a helper column, containing the formula `=COUNTIF(A$2:A$3013,A2)`.

This led to the following chart ("Aantal" is the name of the helper column):

[image]

The information on the top was provided, dragging my mouse above the top point, showing that information as a tooltip. This was indeed what I was looking for and it solved my problem.

This morning, I thought by myself "*Jezus, man, using a `CountIF()` formula with a mixture of absolute and relative references, that's quite complicated. There should be an easier way to obtain this result.*", but after some tests with other chart types (column, histogram, ..., even pivotchart), I did not find one chart type which can select a group of entries, count them and show them and their frequency in a clear way.

Am I right or is there a chart type which covers this?

**Edit after first comment:**
There seems to be an easy solution, but Excel messes it up, trying to analyse the values and turning them into hours and minutes, and perform the count on this, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure to understand you correctly. I would say that’s the purpose of Pivot tables (and consequently Pivot charts): https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-pivottables-and-pivotcharts-527c8fa3-02c0-445a-a2db-7794676bce96  … In this case, you would use this one column of timestamps for both fields in the pivot table: rows and values, and choose to count as aggregation. Apologies if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Anonymous: you might think the situation is that easy, but Excel starts working with hours and minutes, messing up the entire information, as you can see in the edit of my question.

Comment: I don’t have access to Excel right now, but I think the issue you mentioned is related to the grouping and ungrouping of date and time: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725

Comment: Great. Will do so. Cheers!

Comment: @Anonymous: edited (added "Ungrouping" screenshots) and accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To sum up the proposed solution:**

You can use the **Pivot table** (and Pivot chart) feature where you would apply the `timestamp` column for both fields:

- `rows` and `values`, and choose to `count` as aggregation.

In order to adjust the way Excel handles date and time you may want to `group/ungroup` the components of the timestamp to match with your requirements (reference [links](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/group-or-ungroup-data-in-a-pivottable-c9d1ddd0-6580-47d1-82bc-c84a5a340725) see also in the comments).

**Extra remark:**
At first, the pivottable might look as follows (grouping the timestamps per hour):

[image]

Ungrouping can be done, right-clicking in the first column:

[image]

This results in the following correct result:

[image]